# Emacs interactive Python mode delays evaluation

Tags: python, emacs, python-mode

When I run a Python 3.3.4 prompt inside Emacs 24.3 on Windows 7, correct commands are evaluated immediately, but incorrect ones are delayed (I have to press Enter one more time), as seen below:

```
>>> 1
1
>>> nonsense
>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'nonsense' is not defined
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe it wants you to confirm if you wish to evaluate `nonsense`?

Comment: @devnull then how should I "change my mind"?

Comment: Since you were the one to start, it probably doesn't let you have a choice regarding that :)

Comment: Odd. What do you get if you set `nonsense = 1` and then try to evaluate `nonsense`?

Comment: @user2357112 I type `nonsense`, press Enter, no output; type `nonsense=1`, press Enter, get the error message related to the first prompt; then type `nonsense` and press Enter and get 1.

Comment: I'm unable to duplicate this with 3.3.4, Emacs 24.3, and Ubuntu or Fedora. Odd.

Comment: @jozefg Then quite possibly it's a Windows-only problem.

Comment: @marczellm, do you get similar behaviour running `python` directly from `cmd.exe`?